# Building a form that cant submit

Tags: html, forms

Is it possible to build a  in HTML that cannot submit, without using JavaScript?

I want to be able to use `<input type="reset">` and I, of course, I havent added an `<input type="submit">`, but someone could press enter in one of my controls, and that would submit it anyway.

So, is this doable without JavaScript? :)

Comment: What if you make the submit button disabled and only enable it with JavaScript?

Comment: @jdwire Pressing return in a text field will still submit the form.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use JavaScript?

Comment: Great solution. Completely hide the UI and functionality of your site if the client has JS disabled... o.O

Comment: @BenM I don't agree with the OP's desire to make the site not work in JavaScript, but if he must prevent the form from submitting, why not prevent the users from even filling out the form instead of just not letting it submit. Or maybe I don't understand the question.

Comment: I think you have misinterpreted the question, to be honest.

Comment: @jdwire: You misunderstood. Maybe my phrasing wasnt the best. Want I want is that the form NEVER works, no matter what. And I want to do this, without using Javascript. Kinda like you can do "novalidate" on a form to avoid validation. (Sadly there is no "nosubmit") :P

Comment: just fake the submit with a normal button?

`$(document).keypress(
    function(event){
     if (event.which == '13') {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
});`

the javascript will disable the return/enter key

Comment: You are still using JavaScript... I asked for no Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the answer is NO.

Well, it is also an answer, even if it's not the one I wanted :)